# Serve one page of Flask application as Angular app

Tags: angular, flask

I have an existing back office Flask app that uses basic Jinja templating. It works great, but now I'd like to enhance a single page of this app by making it a single page Angular app (no routing). I can run my Flask app http://localhost:5000/, and my Angular app http://localhost:4200/. But for one route in the Flask app I need it to return Angular's index.html. I've found a few other posts which talk about this, but it's more about converting an entire Flask app to Angular. For the time being I only want to deliver a single page as Angular. Here's my directory structure.

```
.
├── angular.json
├── app.py
├── dist
│   └── mailing-list
│       └── browser
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app-routing.module.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.html
│   │   ├── app.component.scss
│   │   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   ├── app.module.ts
│   │   └── mailinglist
│   │       ├── mailinglist.component.html
│   │       ├── mailinglist.component.scss
│   │       └── mailinglist.component.ts
│   ├── assets
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── main.ts
│   └── styles.scss
├── static
└── templates
```

And the relevant bits of my app.py

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    context = {}
    return render_template('index.html', context=context)

@app.route('/mailing-list/') # this is the route I want to return as Angular
def mailing_list():
    context = {}
    return render_template('mailing-list.html', context=context)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=4200)
```

Angular's index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MailingList</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="pure-g outer">
    <h1>Mailing List Manager</h1>
    <app-mailinglist></app-mailinglist>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Angular's probably not the best tool for this use case; it's for full-fat SPAs, something like Vue supports progressive enhancement more easily.

Comment: Hrm. That would be unfortunate since I've already written most of the app.:D

Answer (score 0):

flask needs to serve the `build` version of the angular application so the contents of the dist folder!

You can do development in two servers, `5000` for flask and `4200` for angular

Then when you deploy the code, you can run `npm run build` which will create the built application inside the `dist` folder and copy paste it inside flask during deployment, you can also automate this through CI/CD like github actions

Another way is which developing angular, you can run two commands in two terminals, `ng build --watch` and `npm run start`, this will enable the dist folder to be in sync with your dev server and you can just point flask to the `dist` folder's `index.html`

The Second method might have some flaws like you need to restart the flask server, but the first method is much easier and you can leave the heavy lifting of integrating both the applications to CI/CD!

Also note **the flask APIs must be defined with a prefix like `/api` inorder to differentiate from the angular route, maybe check this article on [`flask serving Single Page Applications`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/singlepageapplications/)

Comment: Thanks for your input Naren, could I ask that you provide a simple illustration of the directory structure for your suggestion? What I think I'm hearing is that the Flask app would be contained inside a "flaskapp" folder (my wording, not yours). Then the Angular app would live inside the src folder. Then when I run npm run build, it would copy the contents of both "flaskapp" and "src" folders into the dist folder, and that's where I could combine the two?